# Editting NSMutableDictionary in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode, dictionary

I've got a question: I've got an NSMutableArray, which I pass on in multiple views. In one of the views, a value of an object inside that array (NSMutableDictionary) can be editted. I do that using the code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tester = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:selectedItem copyItems:YES];
NSMutableString *newLoc = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:locationField.text]; 
[tester setValue:newLoc forKey:@"Location"];
[selectedList replaceObjectAtIndex:[selectedList indexOfObject:selectedItem] withObject:tester];
```

The problem I'm having with this, is replacing that object in selectedList. It gives the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa631e30'`
It works if I copy the new item in a copy-array of selectedList, and alloc selectedList with the new value again, but the other views are having problem finding that same list again in the array (new allocated location).

TL;DR version: how can I edit a value (through replacing?) inside an NSMutableArray? Why doesn't replaceObjectAtIndex work?

EDIT: It was immutable indeed. Still, the main question remains: 
I've got:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tester = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:geselecteerdItem copyItems:YES];
[geselecteerdItem setValue:nieuweLoc forKey:@"Location"];
[geselecteerdeLijst replaceObjectAtIndex:[geselecteerdeLijst indexOfObject:tester] withObject:geselecteerdItem];
```

When I'm using: `[warningList replaceObjectAtIndex:[warningList indexOfObject:geselecteerdeLijst] withObject:keuzeLijst]`, it gives me an outofbounds error because the index of the array geselecteerdeLijst obviously changed inside warningList. Any idea's?

Comment: is selectedItem your dictionary,if yes then does your array selectedList contains dictionaries. please elaborate your data structure.You can put nslog so see whether the value is coming properly or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`selectedList` is an *immutable* array, which doesn't support any modifications. You can do something like this, though:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: selectedList];
[tmp replaceObjectAtIndex:[selectedList indexOfObject:selectedItem] withObject:tester];
```

EDIT: To clarify, `__NSArrayI` is a concrete immutable subclass of `NSArray`, `__NSArrayM` is a mutable one. You should not rely on the private class names, but since they speak for themselves, you can at least know which is mutable and which is not.

Comment: @Joetjah Make sure you add `tester` to `geselecteerdeLijst` before sending `[geselecteerdeLijst indexOfObject:tester]`, because otherwise it will return NSNotFound, which is definitely out of bounds.

Comment: Hi, that's correct, but the error occurs somewhere else. Because I editted an item within geselecteerdeLijst, it somehow editted the array in which geselecteerdeLijst is in. It changed the index of geselecteerdeLijst, while I only replaced an object within geselecteerdeLijst.